# Spark conditional sum function returns null if column name is used

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I interpreted that [spark sum function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#sum-java.lang.String-) can work with string column name. However, I see different results when use `column name` or `column object`.

```
schema = ["department", "employee", "knwos_ops", "developer"]
data = [("frontend", "john", 0, 1,), ("frontend", "jenny", 1, 1,), ("frontend", "michael", 0, 1,)]
input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
input_df.show(5, False)

+----------+--------+---------+---------+
|department|employee|knwos_ops|developer|
+----------+--------+---------+---------+
|frontend  |john    |0        |1        |
|frontend  |jenny   |1        |1        |
|frontend  |michael |0        |1        |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+

input_df \
    .groupBy(*["department"]) \
    .agg( \
            f.sum("developer").alias("dev"), \
            f.sum(f.when(f.col("knwos_ops") == 1, "developer")).alias("devops"), \
            f.sum("knwos_ops").alias("ops"),
    ).show(5, False)
    
+----------+---+------+---+
|department|dev|devops|ops|
+----------+---+------+---+
|frontend  |3  |null  |1  |
+----------+---+------+---+
    
input_df \
    .groupBy(*["department"]) \
    .agg( \
            f.sum("developer").alias("developer"), \
            f.sum(f.when(f.col("knwos_ops") == 1, f.col("developer"))).alias("devops"), \
            f.sum("knwos_ops").alias("ops"),
    ).show(5, False)

+----------+---+------+---+
|department|dev|devops|ops|
+----------+---+------+---+
|frontend  |3  |1     |1  |
+----------+---+------+---+
```

My understanding of functions `sum` and `when` is following,

- function `when` returns value if condition is matched otherwise returns null.
- function `sum` by using either column name of type string or column name of type Column.

Based on this, in first aggregation example, condition  inside `when` function should return column `developer` name as string which should be used by function `sum` to aggregate and return 2. However it return null.

Why spark cannot identify that `developer` is a column of the dataframe. Can someone please help me understand documentation behind this?

**Update**
Thanks for kind replied. As I did in second aggregation, I have way to solve this problem. I am rather looking for explanation behind this behavior and Someone to point out gap in my interpretation of fucntion `sum`.

Let me rephrase it like this. If function sum gets string as arguments, it tries to find a column of same name in the dataframe

```
#### sum function receives string as argument, and finds the column and does the sum
input_df.agg(f.sum("developer")).show(5, False)
+--------------+
|sum(developer)|
+--------------+
|3             |
+--------------+

#### sum function receives string as argument, and finds the column and does the sum. Field type is string so it return null
input_df.agg(f.sum("employee")).show(5, False)
+--------------+
|sum(developer)|
+--------------+
|null          |
+--------------+

#### sum function receives string as argument, and does not find the column and throws error
input_df.agg(f.sum("manager")).show(5, False)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o839.agg.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`manager`' given input columns: [department, employee, knwos_ops, developer];
```

Based on above snippet, I expect function `when` to return string `developer` and
I expect that function `sum` will use that string to resolve column from that string and do aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when` is a bit different from other Spark SQL functions. If you specify a string in the `then`/`otherwise` statement, it will be interpreted as a string literal rather than a column.

For example, a possible use case for string literals might be

```
F.when(F.col('size') > 10, 'large').otherwise('small')
```

and Spark would interpret `large` and `small` as string literals rather than columns.

Therefore, in your use case, you're summing up `'developer'` strings, which returns null because strings cannot be summed.

Due to this ambiguity, it is necessary to specify `F.col` to clarify that you want a column as the result of the `then`/`otherwise` statement.

Comment: As I understand, function `sum` expects only column name (type string/Column) return null only when column type in argument is not numeric. 
What I am missing here?

Comment: `when` returns a **string column** with the literal `developer`. It does not return a string.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is the following instead:

```py
input_df \
    .groupBy(*["department"]) \
    .agg( \
            f.sum("developer").alias("developer"), \
            f.expr("SUM(CASE WHEN knwos_ops = 1 AND developer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS devops"), \
            f.sum("knwos_ops").alias("ops"),
    ).show(5, False)
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to clear my intention behind asking the question.